# MSSQL Server Remote Login Issue on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: sql-server, windows, windows-server-2012-r2

I have installed MSSQL Express 2012 on Windows Server 2012 R2, I have set up database and logins. Everything works fine while I'm logged in at the server, but once I want to login from another machine I got the message:

> "login failed for user sa".

Settings that I have made:

- Added permission for port 1433 in Firewall,
- Named Pipes,
- TCP/IP,
- VIA are enabled from Sql Server Configuration Manager.

Also for TCP/IP I have set IPALL - TCP Dynamic Ports (blank) and TCP Port 1433. ( These settings are used on other versions of windows that are working, but cant get it on Windows Server 2012 R2 when I want to connect from another machine ).

Comment: What do the logs on the host server say? I also **assume** you have enabled remote connections (I think this is enabled by default, but may depend on the SQL Server version you're using)?

Comment: It does not appear in the SQL Server Logs. Remote connection enabled. Version 11.0.2100 ( 2012 )

Comment: If you can't see the connection attempt in the logs, then the connection attempt is never reaching the host server. Is the instance name the default (MSSQLSERVER) or have you given it a different name? Can you see the host in the SQL Server Browse list (Enable the SQl Server browser service, albeit it temporarily and check if it isn't currently on). You've allowed connection to port 1433, I *assume* SQL Server is running on the default port. Edit, also version 11.0.2100??? Why such an old version? That's the base version. I'd **strongly** suggest updating to SP3 GDR at least, if not SP4.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Larnu - I have just checked the instance name and it was another instace, because also on that machine was installed and older version and I was doing settings on that older version using that older Sql Server Configuration Manager.